# Java Spring applicationcontext to registerBeanDefinition

Tags: java, spring

Java Spring 2.5.x

I Have `ApplicationContext` and i want to register bean with params

"beanName", beandefination

```
GenericBeanDefinition myBeanDef = new GenericBeanDefinition();
```

To register bean i need `BeanDefinitionReader` but don't know how to get any help appriciated

```
getRegistry().registerBeanDefinition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following solution works for me.

```
GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext();
        context.setParent(applicationContext);

context.registerBeanDefinition("beandefName", beanDefinitionObject);
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you need a bean definition? If you have a ConfigurableApplicationContext you can use the exposed bean factory:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = ...;
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beans = context.getBeanFactory();
Object bean = new ...; // create and initialize bean 
beans.registerSingleton(beanName, bean);
```

Instead of `Object` use the appropriate bean type and fill in the desired properties before registering. If you want to use autowire you can use

```
Object bean = beans.createBean(Object.class); 
beans.registerSingleton(beanName, bean);
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can try

```
BeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(context);
```

Comment: constructor need beandefinationRegistry and i do not have it